# Is there a way to make my formatting function work?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game out of HTML, JS, and CSS [(link here)](https://incremental-money.bipadtarantaran.repl.co/). I need a function format(a, b), that outputs a string a in base b. I tried a.toString(b) but it did not work. Have you got any other function?

Comment: `format(16, "n-base")` returns 16 not, 14? What exactly is your "formatting function" supposed to be doing?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Log every values, use JS debugger to go line-by-line and debug your code